# Strange getName() result on File in linux

Tags: java, linux, windows

I have some code that reads the name from an UNC path:

```
File f = new File(//fileshare/folder/file.txt)
System.out.println(f.getName())
```

On windows this gives:

```
file.txt
```

but on linux it gives:

```
//fileshare/folder/file.txt
```

why?

Comment: Can you print `File.separatorChar` on both systems, and see what happens?

Answer (score 4):

On my system (Ubuntu 12.04) it gives `file.txt`:

```
$ cat Test.java 
import java.io.File;
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("//fileshare/folder/file.txt");
    System.out.println(f.getName());
  }
}
$ javac Test.java && java Test
file.txt
```

`f.getPath()` returns `/fileshare/folder/file.txt`, which shows that multiple slashes get reduced to one, as is customary (required?) on Unix systems.

Of course, a UNC path is meaningless on anything but Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try using org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils from Apache Commons, the method getName() should ensure consistent parsing of the full path regardless of the platform where you are running.